Bokeh: Feedback from browser once rendering complete?
Currently I use bokeh to display the data generated from another python script main.py.
The workflow is as follows: bokeh runs in a script gui.py and has about 9 plots.
main.py generates the data, stores them into a file file.dict and then sends a udp command to gui.py that the data has been stored.
gui.py uses curdoc().add_periodic_callback(self.udp_callback, 100) to check every 100 ms whether a udp command has been received. If so, it reads the dictionary stored in file.dict and updates each of its plots using basically
def process_data(self,data):
    for ii in range(9):
        for jj in range(4):
            self.plot[ii][jj].data = {"x": data[key[ii]][jj]['x'], "y": data[key[ii]][jj]['y']}

However, the rendering is slow (I have about 4 to 8 plots per figure with about 200 points each) and 100 ms seems to be too short. Unfortunately the computer this is running on doesn't have a GPU either, so I can't use webGL.
Currently I circumvent this by adding an additional counter (self.plot_counter) which gets increased every time I receive an UDP message and refresh the plots only every 10th time or so.
But still, the plots seem to pile up between gui.py and the browser. If I keep it running for a while, even after forcing gui.py and main.py to quit, the browser keeps refreshing the plots several times until it decides it is done. From the console output of gui.py I can see that it stopped requesting new plots after main.py stopped.
At first I thought that maybe the udp messages pile up, but I clear the buffer after reading:
def udp_callback(self):
    data_dict_recv=None
    try:
        txt_recv = self.server.recv()
        if txt_recv == "new data stored":
            with open("/tmp/file.dict","rb") as f:
                data = pickle.load(f)
            while self.server.recv():
                asdf=1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    if data is not None:
        self.process_data(data)

Is there any way to get a feedback from the browser to the script whether the rendering has been completed? I'd like to not request new rendering unless the previous one is finished.
